# n_distinct within a grouped tibble running slow in dplyr 1.0.0

Tags: r, dplyr

I am running n_distinct within a grouped tibble, it seems to be running far slower in dplyr 1.0.0 than it was in previous versions of dplyr.

For example, using a machine with dplyr 0.8.5:

```
> library(dplyr)
> test <- data.frame(a = rep(1:10000, 3), b = round(runif(30000, 0, 3)))
> system.time(tmp <- test %>% group_by(a) %>% mutate(c = n_distinct(b)))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.015   0.000   0.015
```

Using a machine with dplyr 1.0.0:

```
> library(dplyr)
> test <- data.frame(a = rep(1:10000, 3), b = round(runif(30000, 0, 3)))
> system.time(tmp <- test %>% group_by(a) %>% mutate(c = n_distinct(b)))
   user  system elapsed
  2.043   0.000   2.043
```

Is anyone aware of this? Should I be using a different method of doing this in dplyr 1.0.0?

Comment: Using base R's `length(unique(b))` the time is cut by about 98% on my machine.

Comment: Not `tidyverse` specific, but `test %>% group_by(a) %>% mutate(c = sum(!duplicated(b)))` should be fast.

Comment: Open issue on performance drop for `summarize`: [summarize performance drop off with many groups](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/5017), including examples with `n_distinct` and work-arounds.  "_we plan to address it in version 1.1.0_". Likely the same issue for `mutate`?

Comment: Thanks for the alternatives. Can use that until fixed in 1.1.0